# Open file and convert to Plain Text

Tags: vba, ms-word, vbscript

I cannot figure this. I'm trying to open a txt file inside word with:

```
Selection.InsertFile FileName:="Z:\001\B.TXT"
```

Every time I get a popup "convert file from" and I need to manually select "Plain text" otherwise I get mumbo-jumbo characters. I'm trying to automate this inside VBS.

Trying to see which is the Convert format with

```
For Each conv In FileConverters
        MsgBox conv.FormatName
Next conv
```

But I don't see the PlainText displayed.

Comment: `. InsertFile FileName:=myName, ConfirmConversions:=False`

Comment: `ConfirmConversions:=False` will only suppress that menu and choose a default option `Encoded text`. I want to select the `Plain Text` option.

Comment: What you want to do is not doable, as @Flakes has already pointed out you have the option to suppress the confirmation. See [The Official Docuemntation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.insertfile).

Comment: If it's a plain text file why are you not simply using `Documents.Open "Z:\001\B.TXT"`?

Comment: It's VBA. Sorry about that. `Documents.Open` opens same dialogue as `InsertFile`. I need somehow to automatically select `Plain text` by default.

Comment: @sys7em - Word can natively open plain text files so if it opens a dialog then your .txt file isn’t plain text.

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt It's an ANSI encoded txt file. I can open it  fine with notepad.

Comment: I found a workaround. That txt is produced by a DOS accounting app (don't ask). Probably badly encoded too. So using VBA I encode the the txt from ANSI to UTF-8 and voila. I can suppress now that annoying dialogue and use `InsertFile`. Thank you all and especially Timothy Rylatt for the right direction push.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround. Use VBA to encode the the txt file from ANSI to UTF-8. Then suppress the `convert file from` dialogue to use the default `Encoded text`. After that `InsertFile` or any other method will work fine.